# how to show multy username or password from text file to textBox1 or textBox2 c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, import, io

i have created a login form using c# Windows form & i am saving username or password to a text file by submiting login form.

but what i want is:- when i click in my textbox it should show the all saved username or password to choose(username or password) that i have saved so i don't have to insert the same  username or password again.

what i want is like this: http://i49.tinypic.com/rkuats.jpg and http://i46.tinypic.com/21edys1.jpg

and this is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Append,
            FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.Write("Email ID: ");
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Write("Password: ");
            sw.Write(textBox2.Text);
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
            MessageBox.Show("Login Complited", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is AutoComplete. Check out [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx) on C Sharp Corner to see how to enable auto complete

Comment: Also, you may want to think about the security of storing usernames and passwords in text files

Comment: ok, will this work for user or password field currectly i mean when i select the user_id and currect password will selected by password field autometically. just like it works for gmail, yahoo, facebook, etc.

Comment: gmail, yahoo, facebook are not creating the dropdown, your browser does. Your browser is also remembering your password to auto-populate when you select a username. To do something similar you'll need to create a relationship between the two, bind the username to the user textbox and then set the password thru an on-change event. Can I suggest you have a go at the username first, and fix the password later